# Hyperlink in JEditorPane not opening on MAC

Tags: java, macos, swing, joptionpane, jeditorpane

I have a JEditorPane, showing in a JOptionPane, with an URL I want to open before closing my application. It works well on Windows and Linux, but it doesn't work on Mac.

Here is the code :

```
//LINK
String link = "http://www.google.com/";
String link_name = "Google";

//Editor_Pane
JEditorPane editor_pane = new JEditorPane();
editor_pane.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));
editor_pane.setText( /*some text*/  + "<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + link_name + "</a>");
editor_pane.setEditable(false);

//ADD A LISTENER
editor_pane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener(){
    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e){
        if(e.getEventType() == (HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED)){

            //OPEN THE LINK
            try{ Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());
            }catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

            //EXIT
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
});

//SHOW THE PANE
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, editor_pane, "text", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                             JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new Object[] {}, null);
```

The link seems clickable, but nothing happens when I click, even if I try to remove the `Desktop.browse` method and let only the `exit` method.

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks !

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding:

```
editor_pane.setEditable(false);
```

The pane needs to be readonly for links to be clickable. See [JEditorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) for more details:

> The HTML EditorKit will generate hyperlink events if the JEditorPane
>   is not editable (JEditorPane.setEditable(false); has been called).

EDIT:

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.URI;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestLink {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("stackoverflow");
        label.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {  
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {  
                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                    try {
                      Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://stackoverflow.com"));
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  } else { 
                      //TODO 
                  }
            }  
        }); 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarinTaverniers, without it on Windows it did not work as well. You mentioned that '_the link seems clickable_'. Does the cursor change over the link? Try to debug, and see if you get into the `hyperlinkUpdate()`. Or add `System.out.println(e.getEventType());` and see if you get anything printed in a console.

Comment: Well the ".setEditable(false)" was originally in my code, I just forgot to copy/paste it here.. ^^'

Comment: @MarinTaverniers I see, well it is best if you create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Not sure what is your use-case, but wouldn't it be easier to show a label that once clicked will open a url?

Comment: Also, make sure `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()` returns true on your platform.

Comment: With the tests I've done, the `hyperlinkUpdate` method is only called once, when I "enter" in the link zone. And if I change the `EventType` to `ENTERED`, it works. Maybe it's because of the JOptionPane, which can block the Listener ?
Indeed use a label could be a solution !

Comment: See last edit that shows a label, I hope it can help you. @MarinTaverniers

Comment: Works on Mac, too!

Comment: @tenorsax Thanks, it worked ! I just had to change `mouseClicked` (which did nothing) to `mousePressed` ! Now I just have to create a font style which looks like an hyperlink !

Comment: @MarinTaverniers you're welcome! I am glad it helped you.